# Current flow through the diode in the picture below

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, diodes, power-electronics, rectifier

[image: Power Electronics by Ned Mohan, Chapter 5]

*Power Electronics* by Ned Mohan, Chapter 5

In Fig 5-3 (b), how can there be a current i in the circuit when source voltage Vs becomes neagtive? Wouldn't the diode be reverse biased?

Answer (score 2):

The inductor current cannot change in an instant. To reduce the current in the inductor, the voltage must reverse across the inductor. This happens when \$v_d<v_R\$ which occurs at time \$t_1\$. The current changes in the inductor by the defining relation:$$\frac{di}{dt}=\frac{v(t)}{L}$$

Between times \$t_1\$ and \$t_3\$ (Area B), the inductor is acting as a current source forcing the current to continue so the diode remains forward biased.

The current is zero at \$t_3\$. The diode voltage reverses preventing negative current.

Comment: But here's my question, assuming an ideal diode, at all times V(source)=V(inductor) + V(resistor), so even if inductor voltage reduces, it adds up with V(resistor) and equals source voltage. So wouldn't the diode be reverse baised when source voltage goes negative?

Comment: The inductor voltage is negative between t1 and t3 so the diode remains forward based for the portion of the negative half-cycle from t2 to t3.

Answer (score 1):

> ... how can there be a current i in the circuit when source voltage Vs becomes neagtive? Wouldn't the diode be reverse biased?

During the negative half wave, the coil acts as a current source which overcomes the negative input voltage Vs and passes a current through the forward-biased diode.